Idea about "education" questions?
For example this one about universities
From my point of view these questions should be banned once and for all unlsee we want tons of question for "profile evaluation" here and questions about various programms.
Perhaps there should be a FAQ with redirection to more appropriate sources like
 QuantNet or Global Derivatives 

This question is an important thing to be certain before we go public because it's at the heart of what we want this quant.SE to be?
We have wilmott, nuclearphynance, quantnet and there is no need to duplicate what other sites have been doing for years.
wilmott seems to cover a bit of everything, nuclearphynance is by and for professional prop traders and quantnet specializes on quant education (MFE programs, etc)
If we want this community to thrive, it has to provide something unique and of great value. There are no point in trying to answer questions like "what books should i read/which MFE program should I apply?"
It will come up from time to time, but we can point them to Quantnet.com. I will personally guide them to the appropriate resources on Quantnet but if we can gather these off topic into our wiki, it will be less tiresome.
I would love to see this SE to be a place to learn from the real experts, not clustered with questions by quant-wannabies.

I think that you're right.  I would expand this to cover "career" questions as well.  The site should focus on subject matter rather than on meta discussions on the field itself.
While these kinds of questions are generally fun to discuss, they aren't really appropriate for the StackExchange model and will be better served by existing forums (e.g. Wilmott).

Yes, Agree about "Career".

Agreed that the FAQ should point to 
http://www.quantnet.com/mfe-programs-rankings/
I made a similar point on What is the scope of Quant SE? for a list of books. The FAQ should just point to the QuantNet entries.
